# How I can Get my Albums ID using Facebook Graph API.?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-fql

Hello Guys I want to Albums Id so that I can Retrieve all the photos of my albums but my question is how to get Albums Id using Graph API or FQL I am using C#.

Thank you..!!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know your exact scenario. If you really want to retrieve *your* Album IDs and photos, the easiest way to do this is probably with Windows PowerShell and FacebookPSModule (http://facebookpsmodule.codeplex.com), command "Read-FBulkPhotos -AllAlbums".

Comment: Thanks @Jon Newman but I want to access through the Graph api or FQL so is there any way to retrieve exactly you above mentioned.data.

Comment: It's certainly possible -- FacebookPSModule is layered over Facebook C# SDK -- but there are a fair number of steps. Feel free to look at my implementation.